# I am getting Remote Video stream, but its not playing (webrtc)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I am currently in the process of developing a sophisticated video chat website, employing the advanced PeerJS framework. However, I have encountered an unfortunate setback where the remote video stream is not functioning as intended.

[here is logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXQPq.jpg)

I have made attempts to explore alternative solutions from various GitHub projects, but regrettably, none of them have proven successful. In each instance, the remote stream fails to load, posing a persistent challenge.

Furthermore, I had clone certain GitHub projects, yet regrettably, I have encountered similar issues where those have also failed to yield the desired results.